# Error handling in spring integration

Tags: mongodb, message-queue, messaging, spring-integration, enterprise-integration

I am using `mongodb-queue` to send the messages. To handle the errors, I'm using the separate channel which send the exceptions. When sending the exceptions, I need to retrieve the POJO.

Please let me know if you have any idea on how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally shouldn't be messing with the `error-channel` header with a header enricher - that is rarely needed; set an `error-channel` on the inbound endpoint. The message in the error channel will be an `ErrorMessage` with `failedMessage` and `cause` properties. The `failedMessage` is the message at the point of failure.

Comment: Thank you Gary for the reply.